# Edit package.json and append to scripts command line

Tags: json, bash, append, package.json

This `json --in-place -f ./package.json -e 'this.scripts={"foo": "bar"}'` overwrites previously defined scripts. How do I *append* to `scripts` in package.json with json?

Comment: @enrico.bacis Got a few?

Comment: In which language do you want to modify the package.json ?

Comment: @JRichardsz -- I was working with a bash script.

Comment: It is so easy to update a json with pure bash, some tool (json), or with nodejs. Try with sed or nodejs.